# How to "select" columns from an array of struct?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, select, pyspark, struct

I have an array of structs and I want to create a new column, but only select a few columns from the struct.

Currently, I am doing it this way:

```py
F.array(F.struct(
    F.col('orig_column.item_1'),
    F.col('orig_column.item_2'),
    F.col('orig_column.item_3')))
```

However, the schema is not what I want. I get this:

```
root
 |-- orig_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_4: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_5: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_6: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_7: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- new_column: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- item_1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_4: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

What I wanted to happen is:

```
root
 |-- new_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- item_1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- item_3: long (nullable = true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the structs are inside an array, you can "loop" through every element of the array using [**`transform`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) to transform it to whatever you like. The following code selects only desired fields.

**Spark 3.1+**

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([(2, 2, 2, 2,)],)],
    'orig_column:array<struct<item_1:bigint,item_2:bigint,item_3:bigint,item_4:int>>'
)

df = df.withColumn(
    'new_column',
    F.transform(
        "orig_column", 
        lambda x: F.struct(
            x.item_1.alias('item_1'), 
            x.item_2.alias("item_2"), 
            x.item_3.alias("item_3"))
    )
)

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- orig_column: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_1: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_3: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_4: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- new_column: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
#  |    |    |-- item_1: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_2: long (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- item_3: long (nullable = true)
```

**Spark 3.1.2+**

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    'new_column',
    F.expr("transform(orig_column, x -> struct(x.item_1, x.item_2, x.item_3))")
)
```

**Spark 2.4+**

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    'new_column',
    F.expr("transform(orig_column, x -> struct(x.item_1 as item_1, x.item_2 as item_2, x.item_3 as item_3))")
)
```

Comment: I added a usage with the newly added python version of `transform` pyspark function. @ZygD - feel free to revert my edits if you think they're not helpful. Then using python version of `struct` one needs to _`alias`_ the fields to keep the struct names the same.

Comment: @botchniaque - I actually tried to create an example using `F.transform`, but somehow was unable to find the correct syntax, so thank you! :) I just corrected the versions, as I want to be very accurate on them - I've tested them all.